# Determining the cdf of $Y=X^2$

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Question:  Let $X$ be  continuous random variable with pdf
> $f(x)=\frac{2}{9}(x+1)$ for $-1<x<2$. Determine the pdf of $Y=X^2$.
> Now do the same with $-2<x<1$

The solution says:

Observe that $Y=X^2$ has support in $(0,4)$. We divide the problem into two cases. If $y\in (0,1]$ we have that $\{Y\leq y\}=\{-\sqrt{y}\leq X \leq \sqrt{y}\}$

Therefore, the CDF in this case is equal to

$$F_{y}(y) = \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{2}{9}(x+1) dx$$

On the other hand, if $y\in (1,4)$, we have that

$\{Y\leq y\}=\{-1\leq X \leq \sqrt{y}\}$. Therefore the CDF in this case is equal to

$$F_{y}(y) = \int_{-1}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{2}{9}(x+1) dx$$

Then they take the derivative to get the pdf. I'm mainly confused about the first case when $0<y<1$

I don't really understand this. If $-1<x<2$ then $1<X^2=Y<4$.

I guess the only thing I'm thinking is that if $X=0$ then obviously $X^2=Y=0$ but that is not included in the interval (1,4). Even still, I don't understand how they get the bounds $-sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}$

Similarly, for the interval $-2<x<1$ should I split it up into two cases as well? When $y\in (0,1]$ and $y \in (1,4)$.
so when $y in (1,4) then

$$F_y (y) = \int_{-2}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{2}{9}(x+2) dx$$

and when $y\in (0,1]$ then

$$F_y (y) = \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{2}{9}(x+2) dx$$

Comment: If -1 < x < 2, then X can take any value between -1 and 2. In particular X can take values around 0 (and including 0). Y = X^2, so Y can take values of the squares of all the values in the range of -1 to 2, including the square of values around 0, which is 0 as you noted. What is the confusion?

Comment: The bounds are obtained by $F_Y(y) = F_{X^2}(y)  = P(X^2 < y) = P(X < +- \sqrt{y}) = P(-\sqrt{y} < X < \sqrt{y})$

Comment: I guess I am confused about why in the first case the bounds are between $-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}$ but the second case it’s between -1 and $y$

Comment: In the second case, for values $y\in(1,4)$, $X$ must be at least $-1$. The probabilities that $X < -1$ are zero, so they are not of interest.

Comment: oh okay so then for the interval $-2<x<1$ are my two integrals for the cdf correct? I separated into $-\sqrt{y}<x<\sqrt{y}$ and $-2<x<\sqrt{y}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_X(x) = \frac29(x+1)\cdot\mathsf 1_{(-1,2)}(x)$ then $Y=X^2$ takes values in $(0,4)$. For $0<y<1$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y) &= \mathbb P(X^2\leqslant y)\\
&= \mathbb P(X\leqslant \sqrt y)\\
&= \int_{(-\sqrt y,\sqrt y)} f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_{-\sqrt y}^\sqrt y \frac29(x+1)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac49\sqrt y,
\end{align}
and for $1<y<4$ we have
$$
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y) = \int_{-1}^{\sqrt y} \frac29 (x+1)\ \mathsf dx = \frac 19(1+\sqrt y)^2.
$$
The map $x\mapsto \frac29(x+1)$ does not integrate to one over $(-2,1)$, so the second part of the question doesn't make sense.