# $X$ has pdf $f(x)=c(x+1)$ Find pdf of $Y=X^2$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be  continuous random variable with pdf $f(x)=c(x+1)$ for
> $-2<x<1$. Determine the pdf of $Y=X^2$.

I actually asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590275/determining-the-cdf-of-y-x2) question earlier but the second part of the question didn't make sense. I just wanted to verify if my solution for this question is correct.

$\int_{-2}^{1} c(x+1)dx=\frac{3}{2}c$

$c=\frac{2}{3}$

For $0<y<1$

$$P(X\leq \sqrt{y})=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} 2/3 (x+1)dx=\frac{4\sqrt{y}}{3}$$

Taking the derivative, I get

$f_{y}(y)=\frac{2}{3\sqrt{y}}, 0<y<1$

Similarly, for $1<y<4$  the cdf is

$$\int_{-2}^{\sqrt{y}} 2/3(x+1)dx = \frac{y}{3}+2\sqrt{y}$$

Again, taking the derivative I get

$f_y(y)=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$

So finally:

$$f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3\sqrt{y}},  & \text{0<y<1} \\[2ex]
\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}, & \text{1<y<4}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: $P(X^2 \leq y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y})$ when $y \geq 0$.

Think about $y = 3$. How will you find $P(X^2 \leq 3)$?

Comment: oh yes, and also when $y=2$, $x$ cannot be $\sqrt{2}$. so should I change the bounds of the second integral?

Comment: Right! What would be the bounds?

Comment: @jaemmin hmm so for this one it doesn't need to be a piecewise pdf? I can just integrate $\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{2}{3} (x+1) dx$

Comment: We know that $-2 < x < 1$. So, for $y = 2$, the upper bound should be $1$ not $\sqrt{y}$.   You should choose the intersection.

Comment: ohhh I see, so I should still break it up into a piecewise function right? It's just that my second integral for $1<y<4$ should be $\int_{-2}^{1} \frac{2}{3}(x+1)dx$

Comment: @jaemmin shouldn't the second integral then go from -2 to 0? since I did 0 to 1 separately?

Comment: You are getting $P(X^2 \leq y)$. Same X value can be used to compute probability as it's for y.

Comment: @jaemmin sorry I think I am getting confused. should the bounds then be $\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{1}$?

Comment: The range of $X$ is incorrect, or the pdf $f$ is invalid: when $-2 < x < -1$ then $f(x) < 0$

Comment: @Alex so does that mean there is no $c$ for which this pdf is valid? or did i just solve incorrectly

Comment: @user130306 That's right. The integration was correct, but it's not a valid pdf for any $c$. If $c$ was negative then the $f(x)$ would not be valid for any $-1 < x < 1$

Comment: @Alex but I integrated $\int_{-2}^{1} \frac{2}{3}(x+1) dx$ and got 1. so doesn't that mean it is a valid pdf?

Comment: @user130306 But it also has to be non-negative. If you calculate $P(-2 < X < -1)$ by integrating $f$ from $-2$ to $-1$, you get $-1/3$, and if you calculate $P(-1<X<1)$ you get $4/3$, and neither of these make sense

Comment: oh wow, yes I forgot about that condition. thank you so much. so i guess I should just say there is no value of $c$ for which this is a valid pdf?

Comment: @user130306 You're welcome. Yes, I think you should say that the pdf must be invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alex said, $c(x+1)$ becomes both negative, positive value on $-2 < x < 1$, which makes $f$ not a pdf.

To make $f$ a pdf, you should separate $c$ within the range with proper $c$'s.

i.e. $c_1(x+1)$ in ($-2 < x < -1$), $c_2(x+1)$ in ($-1 < x < 1$)

---

Let's ignore the negative value problem and consider the integration parts.

Let's keep in mind that the support of $x$ is $(-2, 1)$

\begin{align}
 F_Y(y) &= P(Y \leq y) \\
&=  P(X^2\leq y)\\
&= P(- \sqrt y  \leq X \leq \sqrt y)
\end{align}

For $0 < y < 1$,
\begin{align}
-1 < - \sqrt y \leq X \leq \sqrt y < 1
\end{align}

So, the interval is contained in the support.

Thus,

\begin{align}
F_Y(y) = \int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y} f_X(x)  dx
\end{align}

For $1 < y < 4$,
\begin{align}
1 < \sqrt y < 2 \text{  and} -2< -\sqrt y < -1 \\ 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
-2 < -\sqrt y \leq X < 1 < \sqrt y < 2
\end{align}

So, the interval $[- \sqrt y, \sqrt y]$ is not contained in the support.

Thus, we should get the **intersection** of $[- \sqrt y, \sqrt y]$ and **support**(=$(-2, 1)$) as integration interval which is
\begin{align}
[- \sqrt y, 1)
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{align}
F_Y(y) = \int_{-\sqrt y}^{1} f_X(x)  dx
\end{align}

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141152/discussion-on-answer-by-jaemmin-x-has-pdf-fxcx1-find-pdf-of-yx2).